# Save Bitmap to same file it was loaded from

Tags: c++, .net, windows, bitmap

I am trying to save a [Bitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) to the same file I loaded it from. However I am unable to do so. I am aware that the documentation for the .save() function says "Do not save an image to the same stream that was used to construct the image. Doing so might damage the stream" and think this is the cause of my issue.
For example, if I load the image "a.jpg" I am unable to save the modified file back to "a.jpg", I must change the file name.

This is my code for loading the image:

```
std::string fullPath = imgFolderPath + "\\" + imageFileNames[i];
std::wstring wstr(fullPath.begin(), fullPath.end());
Bitmap* bitmap = new Bitmap(wstr.c_str());
```

and my code to save the image is:

```
bitmap->Save(wstr.c_str(), &clsid, NULL);
```

This works fine when the file name is different. Is there a way that I can write to the same image? I would rather "update" the image than create a new one entirely.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you store the image into a buffer why don't you just delete the image ex.'system("rm foo.png")' and then write?

Comment: Do you mean store it into a temporary file and then write it when the original is closed? I was trying to avoid that, as their will normally be about 1000 images or so in a batch.

Comment: your buffer is variable *bitmap. ^^

Comment: The documentation says that "The file remains locked until the Bitmap is disposed", so I dont think I can really do anything to the original while the buffer exists...

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just close the existing Bitmap stream and then open a new one for writing with the same file name? That should then overwrite the original image.

Comment: According to the documentation "The file remains locked until the Bitmap is disposed."...

Comment: Can you point us to the documentation containing the text "The file remains locked until the Bitmap is disposed."?

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion I saw from jlpilkin in the [Community Additions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536316(v=vs.85).aspx) portion of the GDI+ documentation suggests not creating the Bitmap directly from the file.  Instead, read the file into a memory buffer, create a memory stream, and then create the Bitmap from the memory stream.  Once the Bitmap is created, you can release the memory stream and the memory buffer.  Now you have a Bitmap that's not holding the original file open.

I would then save the modified bitmap to a temporary name, and use ReplaceFile to atomically move it to the original file name, preserving the original file's attributes.